# SSRS - Calculation of rows using column total

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I'm using a matrix tablix style to display a range of date based on date range parameter. The image below indicates CAT1 to CAT20 with Case Count total. I need assistance on how to calculate the Case % base on overall Case Count.

For example: Total Case Count = 3,393, CAT1 = 11, Case % for CAT1 = 0.324% (11 / 3,393). I am having difficulty figuring a way to calculate Case % using the overall Case Count.

I wrote a code in SQL, but when I add it in SSRS dataset it is timing out. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Here is the 4 days data (Note: This is the actual report). I have 2 datasets 1) RSNCD_SUB is by date, counting case by category (Reason Code). 2) RSNCD_TTL is by date, counting cases by data, and I'm using tablix matrix.
[image]

[image]

Below is the comparison when running the report using multiple date vs single date. As you can see the calculation on a 1 day run is correct, but it is incorrect on a multiple day run.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your second data column is in the same column group as the first. Then use the following expression, where `"DAY"` is your column group:

```
=Sum(Fields!CASE_COUNT.Value) / Sum(Fields!CASE_COUNT.Value, "DAY")
```

The first `Sum` has no scope specified, so only includes values for the relevant category and date. The second `Sum` will include all the values for that day, regardless of the category grouping.

Remember to put formatting on the cell with this expression to display it as a percentage, e.g. `0.000%`

[image]

[image]

**Edit:**

By using `"DAY"` as the scope, the percentages for each day are independent. If instead you want the percentage values relative to the entire matrix, use the matrix name  e.g. `"Tablix1"` instead of `"DAY"`.

If some categories have no values on certain days, you can use an `IIF` to leave the cell blank instead of displaying 0%:

```
=IIF(Sum(Fields!CASE_COUNT.Value) > 0, 
  Sum(Fields!CASE_COUNT.Value) / Sum(Fields!CASE_COUNT.Value, "Tablix3"),
  nothing)
```

Comment: Thanks Pete. It works when it is a single date. The category column data can have more category (Cat 21 on 3/21, Cat 22 on 3/23 etc. etc.). If it's a single date from 3/20 let say Cat1 has 34 and Total for 3/20 is 169=20.12, but when run the report from 3/24 to 3/26 the calculation is not correct.

Comment: @Arsee So when you use multiple dates, you want the percentages to be for all the counts across all dates? If so, the new expression I added to my answer should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks. So the "DAY" is the Dataset name and "Tablix1" is the property name right?

Comment: @Arsee When you select your matrix, the Row Groups and Column Groups should appear at the bottom of the screen. `"DAY"` is a column group. `"Tablix1"` is the `Name` of the matrix in it's properties. Your Dataset name shouldn't matter for this purpose.

Comment: The Column Group is showing the Date and Row Group is showing the Category.

Comment: @Arsee It sounds like your matrix is set up the way I expected. I've now added a screenshot of the design view for my version.

Comment: Pete that is exactly what I have (above image), but it's odd that when I run the report for 1 days the % calculation is correct, but the moment I run the report for more than one day then the calculation becomes incorrect.

Comment: Figured it out!! use ReportItems!TextBox_name.valuie.  Found it in a blog post from MSDN. Thanks.